# The EXE file is disappear from obj\Debug and cannot run the Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am working on Windows Forms App C# in Visual Studio 2019,
Every thing was go fine, but after I have finish the project and try to run it this error appear:

```
Error   CS2012  
Cannot open 'E:\Special\Business\Invoice\obj\Debug\Invoice.exe' for writing -- 
'Access to the path 'E:\Special\Business\\Invoice\obj\Debug\Invoice.exe' is denied.
```

The EXE file is disappear from folder: **obj\Debug**

I make full disk scan for Virus and clean everything, and I delete the project and make new one from the beginning, but the same Error happen again

Any help please?

Comment: File/folder permissions issues? Did you run VS previously as Admin? Is that exe currently running? Is there a process locking that file? Can you delete the Debug folder manually and recompile?

Comment: Close VS, delete `obj` and `bin`, restart you computer, try again. I've had an issue similar to this a few times recently and that solved it.

Comment: Llama, thank you , yes, it solve the problem and it run again right, but what was the problem? Is it was virus issue or what? any idea? Make your comment as a solution so 
 I can accept it